# Call or schedule rest api from Hangfire scheduler

Tags: hangfire

I have a .net web api and controllers for example say i have a HomeController and post method that insert to table. I want to call the HomeController in HangFire scheduler with in the same api. The scheduler will run every hour. Is it possible to call the rest api (HomeController) post method by scheduling the Hangfire in the same api.

a. I have web api with HomeController with post method
b. I configured the hangfire in the web api (startup.cs) etc...
c. Now setup the recurring job!!!

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => http://localhost:58664/api/home, Cron.Hourly);

I can generate the values in for loop to post.

Is this possible? calling the rest api with in the same web api using hangfire.

Answer (score 0):

create an instance of home controller and call the method in your loop

//Ex : 
//oEmail = set values here

WebApiRole.SendController oController = new WebApiRole.SendController();

```
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => oController.SendEmail(oEMail), Cron.Hourly);//inside the loop
```

//SendController is the controller name and SendEmail is the method to which I am passing //oEmail as param

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ... quick question what version of .net you are using  I don't see "WebApiRole."   in my version which API it belongs to....